# A single js function to create 9 different alerts on buttons

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I am creating a button in a div so when we click it show us detailed information of the person given in API.  But now I am confused about how to do this like I have 9 divs and every div has its own button, I am using `onClick()` on button it works well for the single button but to show information of 9 people if I use 9 different `onClick()` function it will create redundancy in code so how a single function can handle all this?

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="show" name="button">Details</button>
```

Comment: Please add full html code so that we can help you in better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage [event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) and [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) API to do that with only one event listener and only one handler.

```js
const root = document.getElementById('root');

const handler = (e) => {
  // target IS THE CLICKED BUTTON.
  const {target} = e;
  
  if (target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    alert(`${target.name} has been pressed.`);
  }
};

root.addEventListener('click', handler);
```

```html
<div id='root'>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="button" name="Button 1">Details</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="button" name="Button 2">Details</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="button" name="Button 3">Details</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="button" name="Button 4">Details</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="button" name="Button 5">Details</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="button" name="Button 6">Details</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="button" name="Button 7">Details</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="button" name="Button 8">Details</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="button" name="Button 9">Details</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You really did a hard unsolved algorithm lol.

Comment: @AmirrezaAmini you know that is not true. What is true is that many developers use events without really understanding how they work. And that makes an important difference in code cleanliness, readability and  performance.

Comment: Your code is actually so complicated, I can do it in two lines and he will understand me the first time reading it. I don't understand why you used object dest in the func :llll

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this. Don't forget to defer execution when importing into your html file:

```js
const alert = (e) => {
    window.alert(e.target.innerHTML);
}

const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
for (const btn of buttons) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", alert);
}
```

Comment: There is no need to add one listener for each button. Only one listener is needed in a parent element.

Comment: Won't your code create an alert for every button (as you only check against the tagName) regardless of whether the class is the one specified by the OP?

Comment: Just for every button inside the parent element, yes. Obviously the OP will have to add its own filtering logic inside the event handler.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use **querySelectorAll()**. That means you select all of
   the buttons. What you must pass in the braces is a CSS selector like
   this: *const button = **document.querySelectorAll('button')***.
2. After that you must use [forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp). That is a callback function and that will apply the command/event on every single button. e.g. what you're gonna do if x button gets clicked.

Using **querySelectorAll & forEach** together is the most recommended for these use cases.

```js
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

button.forEach(e => {
  // e here means every single button, doesn't matter which one
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('h1').textContent += 1;
    }
  )}
)
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button" name="button">Details</button>
<button type="button" class="button" name="button">Details</button>
<button type="button" class="button" name="button">Details</button>
<button type="button" class="button" name="button">Details</button>
<button type="button" class="button" name="button">Details</button>
<h1>Result here: </h1>
```

Comment: You "must" not add one event listener for each single button. You can just leverage event bubbling. More info about events [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: I don't understand what's your problem.

Comment: I don't have any problem. It is just that you are asserting that the OP must use `forEach` and that it is the most recommended way to go and none of that is true. The recommended way is to leverage JS event system behavior. 1 event listener against 9 (or potentially more) is way more efficient.

Comment: but no one cares about your opinion. I showed him the most recent and modern syntax.

Comment: Mine is not an opinion. It is a fact that your code reflects poor knowledge about events and that it does not perform as efficiently as it could. You are free to do as you want, but this kind of things matter if you have any intention of being a good developer.

Answer (score -2):

if every div have its on button so you can find its id on button click

```
 <button type="button" id="btn1" class="button" onclick="show(this)" name="button">Details</button>
```

here is javascript function

```
function show(btn){
   const id = btn.getAttribute("id"); // here you will get "btn1"
   if(id == "btn1"){
        
  }
}
```

Comment: OP is asking for a way to avoid adding `onclick` to each button separately.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano he doesn't asking to avoid onclick for each. he want to avoid for create each function separately.

Comment: He is trying to avoid redundancy. And your code is redundant because you will have at least 9 `onclick="show(this)"` that can be avoided.